# How to know if a function is called inside redux thunk dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm writing a function to send API requests. When I get the response from that API I want to dispatch redux action if the user has called my function in dispatch or just do nothing if not. I'm using [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

Right now I've written two separate methods for this.

> 1. This does not dispatch after getting the response from the API, just return the Promise.

```
const getAnimalsList = () => return axios.request({url: 'api.domain.com/animals'});
```

**This function will be called as usual functions.**

---

> 2. It dispatches an action something after getting a response from the API

```
const getAnimalsList = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.request({url: 'api.domain.com/animals'}).then(
        res => dispatch({type: 'RESPONSE RECEIVED', data: res}),
        err => dispatch({type: 'ERROR', err})
    );
}
```

**This function will be called inside dispatch as `dispatch(getAnimalsList())`**

---

Now what I want is to know in a single function whether it was called inside the **dispatch** or just called normally.

example:

```
const getAnimalsLis = () => {
    let prom = axios.reques({url: 'api.domain.com/animals});
    if(function_is_called_inside_dispatch){
        return dispatch => {
            prom.then(
                res => dispatch({type: 'RESPONSE RECEIVED', data: res}),
                err => dispatch({type: 'ERROR', err})

            );
        }
    }
    else return prom;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wrong way to do things. There's no way to detect that the function was called like `dispatch(getAnimalsList())` or just `getAnimalsList()`. Due to operator precedence, it has already been called as `getAnimalsList()` when an action provided to `dispatch`. The only way would be to call it differently, `dispatch(getAnimalsList(CALLED_AS_AN_ACTION))`.

A correct way is to not mix functions that serve different purposes. The code can be made DRYer than it is, `getAnimalsList` function already contains common code that could be extracted otherwise:

```
const getAnimalsList = () => return axios.request({url: 'api.domain.com/animals'});

const getAnimalsListAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    return getAnimalsList().then(
        res => dispatch({type: 'RESPONSE RECEIVED', data: res}),
        err => dispatch({type: 'ERROR', err})
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not define `getState` if you are not planning on using it:

```
const getAnimalsList = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.request({url: 'api.domain.com/animals'}).then(
        res => dispatch({type: 'RESPONSE RECEIVED', data: res}),
        err => dispatch({type: 'ERROR', err})
    );
}
```

And also use the `async/await` syntax, its more explicit for you as to what is going on:

```
export const getAnimalsList = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await jsonAnimals.get("/animals");
  dispatch({ type: "RESPONSE_RECEIVED", payload: response.data });
};
```

Then create a folder/file system like so: `apis/jsonAnimals.js`:

Place your Axios code in there:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://api.domain.com'
});
```

Okay, now you have a nice clean Redux application, makes it easier on the eyes, easier to debug.

Now if you want to test it in the console then you could do

```
export const testGetAnimalsList = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(getAnimalsList());
  console.log(getState().animals);
};

export const getAnimalsList = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await jsonAnimals.get("/animals");
  dispatch({ type: "RESPONSE_RECEIVED", payload: response.data });
};
```